# Circular Arrays in Queues 

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

How is mod used to determine the beginning and end of a circular array in a queue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, usually you keep track of the index of the first element, and the current size. If the size is equal to the size of the array, that means the array is full. Enqueuing a new item then requires you to grow the array. Otherwise, you just write to element `(start + size + 1) % array_size`.

When you *dequeue* an element, you just take the element at `start`, overwrite it with null to allow for garbage collection, decrement `size`, and increment `start`, wrapping to 0 if necessary.

An alternative to keeping track of `start` and `size` is to keep track of `start` and `next` - where `next` is the index of the next element to be enqueued. You spot if the array is full when `start == next`. Then enqueuing (when not full) only requires you to change `next`, and dequeuing only requires you to change `start`. As before, you need to wrap when you increment or decrement `start`/`next`.

Answer (score 0):

In a circular array the rear of queue is `(front + number_of_elements_in_queue - 1) mod size_of_queue` and front of the queue should be tracked after each dequeue.